# how to add a newline after each append in list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, tuples, newline

I have a list of tuples in rows which I need to append to another list and add a newline after each entry I tried everything I can think of but I cant seem to do it properly
here is the code:

```
niz = ["""
(5, 6, 4)
(90, 100, 13), (5, 8, 13), (9, 11, 13)
(9, 11, 5), (19, 20, 5), (30, 34, 5)
(9, 11, 4)
(22, 25, 13), (17, 19, 13)
"""]

list = []
    for n in niz:
        list.append(n)   
    list = '\n'.join(list)
    print(list)
```

This is the closest I get:

```
(5, 6, 4)
(90, 100, 13), (5, 8, 13), (9, 11, 13)
(9, 11, 5), (19, 20, 5), (30, 34, 5)
(9, 11, 4)
(22, 25, 13), (17, 19, 13)
```

But I need it to be:

```
[(5, 6, 4),
 (90, 100, 13), (5, 8, 13), (9, 11, 13),
 (9, 11, 5), (19, 20, 5), (30, 34, 5),
 (9, 11, 4),
 (22, 25, 13), (17, 19, 13)]
```

Comment: Why do your lines have different numbers of "tuples" on them?

Answer (score 0):

When you write

```py
niz = ["""
(5, 6, 4)
(90, 100, 13), (5, 8, 13), (9, 11, 13)
(9, 11, 5), (19, 20, 5), (30, 34, 5)
(9, 11, 4)
(22, 25, 13), (17, 19, 13)
"""]
```

You are creating a list with a single string, and not a list of tuples. I would do something like this:

```py
niz = ["[",(5, 6, 4), "\n", (90, 100, 13), (5, 8, 13), (9, 11, 13), "\n", (9, 11, 5), (19, 20, 5), (30, 34, 5), "\n", (9, 11, 4), "\n", (22, 25, 13), (17, 19, 13),"]"]

for item in niz:
   print(item, end=" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I suggest:

```py
nizz = niz[0].replace(')\n(', '), (')
nizz = nizz.replace('), (', ')|(').replace('\n', '')
result = [eval(i) for i in nizz.split('|')]
```

It gives you the list of all tuples